# Send Identifiable SMS

Tags: java, android, sms

I am writing an Android application that needs to communicate via sms.  So for example application will send a message "Hi" to number 123, when number 123 receives the message it will be parsed on their phone by my application and acted on if it was determined to have been sent by my app.

Now I have the sending and receiving/parsing of messages working perfectly but I need a way to identify that the message was sent by my app.  I could easily semd the message as "appName:hi" and check to see if the body contains 'appName' but the problem is if the user who receives my message doesn't have my app I would prefer if they just saw "Hi".  So I was wondering if theres a way for example to send invisible characters or set some other identifying information either in the sms body or as part of the sms itself ie header.  I would like to avoid data sms if possible and my app is intended to be offline.

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify port when sending SMS. I do not know how to do this with Android API but since this feature has being supported for years by J2ME Android must support it too.

Your application should listen to this port and send to the same port. So, if user already has your application I think he even will not see the message in his inbox. At least this was the behavior in J2ME. If however he does not have the application yet he will either see it in inbox or will not see it at all. Check this with android. As far as I remember in J2ME it depends on the phone model.

Comment: Thanks for that.. this works like I need it to and was easy to implement (Loads of example on SO).. :-)